# Why it's impossible to declare an induction principle for Church numerals

Tags: type-theory, lambda-calculus, dependent-type

Imagine, we defined natural numbers in dependently typed lambda calculus as Church numerals. They might be defined in the following way:

```
SimpleNat = (R : Set) → R → (R → R) → R

zero : SimpleNat
zero = λ R z _ → z

suc : SimpleNat → SimpleNat
suc sn = λ R z s → s (sn R z s)

SimpleNatRec : (R : Set) → R → (R → R) → SimpleNat → R
SimpleNatRec R z s sn = sn R z s
```

However, it seems that we can't define Church numerals with the following type of Induction principle:

```
NatInd : (C : Nat -> Set) -> (C zero) -> ((n : Nat) -> C n -> C (suc n)) -> (n : Nat) -> (C n)
```

Why is it so? How can I prove this? It seems that the problem is with defining a type for Nat which becomes recursive. Is it possible to amend lambda calculus to allow this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The question you are asking is interesting and known. You are using the so-called impredicative encoding of the natural numbers. Let me explain a bit of the background.

Given a type constructor $T : \mathsf{Type} \to \mathsf{Type}$, we might be interested in the "minimal" type $A$ satisfying $A \cong T(A)$. In terms of category theory $T$ is a functor and $A$ is the initial $T$-algebra. For example, if $T(X) = 1 + X$ then $A$ corresponds to the natural numbers. If $T(X) = 1 + X \times X$ then $A$ is the type of finite binary trees.

An idea with long history is that the initial $T$-algebra is the type
$$A \mathrel{{:}{=}} \prod_{X : \mathsf{Type}} (T(X) \to X) \to X.$$
(You are using Agda notation for dependent products, but I am using a more traditional mathematical notation.) Why should this be? Well, $A$ essentially encodes the recursion principle for the initial $T$-algebra: given any $T$-algebra $Y$ with a structure morphism $f : T(Y) \to Y$, we get an algebra homomorphism $\phi : A \to Y$ by
$$\phi(a) = a \, Y \, f.$$
So we see that $A$ is *weakly* initial for sure. For it to be initial we would have to know that $\phi$ is unique as well. This is not true without further assumptions, but the details are technical and nasty and require reading some background material. For instance, if we can show a satisfactory [*parametricty* theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametricity) then we win, but there are also other methods (such as massaging the definition of $A$ and assuming the $K$-axiom and function extensionality).

Let us apply the above to $T(X) = 1 + X$:
$$\mathsf{Nat} =
  \prod_{X : \mathsf{Type}} ((1 + X) \to X) \to X =
  \prod_{X : \mathsf{Type}} (X \times (X \to X)) \to X = \\
  \prod_{X : \mathsf{Type}} X \to (X \to X) \to X.
$$
We got Church numerals! And we also understand now that we will get a recursion principle for free, because the Church numerals *are* the recursion principle for numbers, but we will not get induction without parametricity or a similar device.

The tehcnical answer to your question is this: there exist models of type theory in which the type `SimpleNat` contains *exotic* elements that do not correspond to numerals, and moreover, these elements break the induction principle. The type `SimpleNat` in these models is too big and is only a *weak* initial algebra.

Comment: I agree that the answer is great, but a few references might be useful here: [Geuvers' paper on non-derivability of induction](http://www.cs.ru.nl/~herman/PUBS/IndNonder.ps.gz) and [Neel K's and Derek Dreyer's paper on getting (some) induction from parametricity](https://www.mpi-sws.org/~neelk/final-csl-internalizing-parametricity.pdf). I'm not aware of a paper that fully explores the relationship though.

Comment: I am not too strong on references in this area, thanks @cody!

Comment: @AndrejBauer I have tried to derive that `A = forall X. (F X -> X) -> X` is the initial F-algebra by using parametricity but I don't seem to get quite the right result. There are easily written implementations of functions `fix: F A -> A` and `unfix: A -> F A`. I am using the parametricity theorem for the type signature `forall X. (F X -> X) -> X` and I am trying to show that `unfix . fix = id`.  But it only follows that `unfix . fix` equals a certain function of type `A -> A`, namely, `\a -> a(fix)`,  that is not obviously equal to identity. What am I missing?

Comment: I was using dinaturality and I was missing the fact that the parametricity theorem is stronger than naturality or dinaturality. It is possible to use "strong dinaturality" to prove that `unfix . fix = id`. For that, one needs to show that "strong dinaturality" holds for type signatures `forall X. (F X -> X) -> X`. This gives a shortcut for the proof, without having to resort to fully general relational parametricity.