# Dependent types over Church-encoded type in PTS/CoC

Tags: type-theory, type-systems, dependent-type

I'm experimenting with pure type systems in Barendregt's lambda cube, specifically with the most powerfull one, the Calculus of Constructions. This system has sorts `*` and `BOX`. Just for the record, below I'm using the concrete syntax of the `Morte` tool https://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-Morte-Library which is close to the classical lambda calculus.

I see we can emulate inductive types by some kind of Church-like encoding (a.k.a. Boehm-Berarducci isomorphism for algebraic data types).
For a simple example I use type `Bool = ∀(t : *) -> t -> t -> t` with the constructors `True = λ(t : *) -> λ(x : t) -> λ(y : t) -> x` and `False = λ(t : *) -> λ(x : t) -> λ(y : t) -> y`.

I see that the type of term-level functions `Bool -> T` is isomorphic to pairs of type `Product T T` with classical `Product = λ(A : *) -> λ(B : *) -> ∀(t : *) -> (A -> B -> t) -> t` modulo parametricity by means of function `if : Bool -> λ(t : *) -> t -> t -> t` which is in fact identity.

All questions below will be about representations of dependent types `Bool -> *`.

1. I can split `D : Bool -> *` into pair of `D True` and `D False`. Are there the canonical way to create `D` again? I want to reproduce isomosphism `Bool -> T = Product T T` by an analogue of function `if` at type level but I cannot write this function as simple as original `if` because we cannot pass kinds in arguments like types.
2. I use a kind of an inductive type with two constuctors to solve question(1). The high level description (Agda-style) is the following type (used instead of type-level `if`)

   ```
   data BoolDep (T : *) (F : *) : Bool -> * where
     DepTrue : T -> BoolDep T F True
     DepFalse : F -> BoolDep T F False
   ```

   with the following encoding in PTS/CoC:

   ```
   λ(T : *) -> λ(F : *) -> λ(bool : Bool ) ->
   ∀(P : Bool -> *) ->
   ∀(DepTrue : T -> P True ) ->
   ∀(DepFalse : F -> P False ) ->
   P bool
   ```

   Is my encoding above correct?
3. I can write down the constructors for `BoolDep` like this code for `DepTrue : ∀(T : *) -> ∀(F : *) -> T -> BoolDep T F True`:

   ```
   λ(T : *) ->  λ(F : *) ->  λ(arg : T ) ->
   λ(P : Bool -> *) ->
   λ(DepTrue : T -> P True ) ->
   λ(DepFalse : F -> P False ) ->
   DepTrue arg
   ```

but I cannot write down the inverse function (or any function in the inverse direction). Is it possible? Or should I use another representation for `BoolDep` to produce an isomorphism `BoolDep T F True = T`?

Comment: Very nice question. I've just a small problem I've troubles understanding why $\text{Product T T}$ should be equal to $\text{Bool} \to T$.
Expanding the definitions $\text{Bool} \to T$ should be $(\forall (t : *) \to (t \to t \to t)) \to T$ while $\text{Product} T T$ should be equal to $\forall (t : *) \to ((T \to T \to t) \to t)$, so why should these two types be the same? Or have I done some errors in my calculations?

Comment: @Giorgio Mossa see http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/30923/why-its-impossible-to-declare-an-induction-principle-for-church-numerals - if you have parametricity (not in all models but in the initial (syntactic) one) then you have the isomorphism.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do this using the traditional Church encoding for `Bool`:

```
#Bool = ∀(Bool : *) → ∀(True : Bool) → ∀(False : Bool) → Bool
```

... because you can't write a (useful) function of type:

```
#Bool → *
```

The reason why, as you noted, is that you can't pass in `*` as the first argument to `#Bool`, which in turn means that the `True` and `False` arguments may not be types.

There are at least three ways you can solve this:

1. Use the Calculus of Inductive Constructions.  Then you could generalize the type of `#Bool` to:

   ```
   #Bool = ∀(n : Nat) → ∀(Bool : *ₙ) → ∀(True : Bool) → ∀(False : Bool) → Bool
   ```

   ... and then you would instantiate `n` to `1`, which means you could pass in `*₀` as the second argument, which would type-check because:

   ```
   *₀ : *₁
   ```

   ... so then you could use `#Bool` to select between two types.
2. Add one more sort:

   ```
   * : □ : △
   ```

   Then you would define a separate `#Bool₂` type like this:

   ```
   #Bool₂ = ∀(Bool : □) → ∀(True : Bool) → ∀(False : Bool) → Bool
   ```

   This is essentially a special case of the Calculus of Inductive constructions, but produces less reusable code since now we must maintain two separate definitions of `#Bool`, one for each sort that we wish to support.
3. Encode `#Bool₂` directly within the Calculus of Constructions as:

   ```
   #Bool₂ = ∀(True : *) → ∀(False : *) → *
   ```

If the goal is to use this directly within unmodified `morte` then only approach #3 will work.

Comment: As I can see, we cannot convert #Bool₁ -> #Bool₂, isn't it?

Comment: @ZeitRaffer That's right.  You can't convert from `#Bool₁` to `#Bool₂`

Comment: Hmm... IIUC you call "Calculus of Inductive Constructions" a calculus with an infinite hierarchy of types, but AFAIK the original CIC did not have such a thing (it only added Inductive types to the CoC).  You may be thinking of the Luo's ECC (Extended calculus of constructions)?